# libcurl + cookies on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, cookies, ios9, libcurl

I have a small http C++ lib which is basically a thin wrapper around `libcurl`. I am using this lib to access websites (e.g. login, check/download something, like invoices etc.).

In my latest iOS project, I am also trying to use this `libcurl` wrapper to access a website (login, read messages, send messages, its basically a messenger app). However one thing which I cannot get to work is **cookies**. My intended behaviour would be, that my iOS app (`libcurl`, that is) stores cookies after logging in to the website, so that the app does not need to login every time the app is opened.

To achieve this, I tried to set the `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` options to the `libcurl` session handle. My understanding was that I should set those options to the same filepath in order for `libcurl` to be able to both load and store cookies.

I am setting this path to the full file path of my iOS sandbox documents directory.
However, it seems like the cookie file is never created, and thus the intended behaviour will not work.

Is there anything special to consider, or could anyone give me a hint of what I might be doing wrong?

I am using this build of `libcurl` on iOS: https://github.com/sinofool/build-libcurl-ios

Comment: that should work. Does your app have permission to read/write files there? Enable VERBOSE mode and see if libcurl tells you anything. Note that libcurl doesn't write any cookie file until you close the easy handle.

Comment: Yes the app does have permissions, I'm also dowloading/saving images in the same directory.
Maybe the closing will be an issue, ill check that.

Comment: Seemed to work. I am explicitely closing the handle and app shutdown/background, and now the cookie file is written. It is also reopened and reused upon restart :)
If you add your answer as reply I can accept it.

Comment: Unless you are trying to build a cross-platform project, why would you use libcurl, when you can use the native `NSURLSession`? Note that I love `curl` and `libcurl`, but for a native iOS project, it definitely does not seem (to me) to be the optimal solution.

Comment: I have a ready to use framework as c++ lib, and I also want to use it non-iOS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should just work! Does your app have permission to read/write files there? Enable VERBOSE mode and see if libcurl tells you anything. Note that libcurl doesn't write any cookie file until you close the easy handle.